# Problem with UUID and GUID

Tags: c#, java-me, bluetooth, guid, uuid

Please don't mark this as duplicate. I have gone through all posts on this topic but couldn't solve my problem.

I have an application in J2ME that searches for bluetooth services with a particular UUID:

```
UUID[] uuidSet = { new UID("100000",true) };
int[] attrSet = {0x0100, 0x0003, 0x0004};
int transID = agent.searchServices(attrSet,uuidSet,remoteDevice,this);
```

I have a desktop application in VB.NET using 32feet.NET library that creates a new bluetooth service with a particular GUID.

```
Sub startBluetoothListener()
    Dim lsnr As New BluetoothListener(MyConsts.MyServiceUuid, record)
    lsnr.Start()
    Dim conn As New BluetoothClient
    Dim peerStream As Stream            
End Sub

Class MyConsts
Public Shared ReadOnly MyServiceUuid As Guid _
  = New Guid("{7dc53df5-703e-49b3-8670-b1c468f47f1f}")
End Class
```

Now as per rules, in order to function both GUID/UUID should match. However in .NET the GUID is represented as a hexadecimal string and in JAVA it's different. I googled a lot about how to sync the J2ME and .NET GUID/UUID but could not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the source for the j2me implementation of UUID, and it simply seems to indicate that you omit the braces and the hyphens i.e. use:

```
new UUID("7dc53df5703e49b38670b1c468f47f1f", false)
```

if you use the true parameter, it expects a short-form UUID (i.e. 8 characters long)

My original answer was based on the J2SE implementation, viz:

> isn't the constructor for a UUID from a string:
>
> UUID aUUID = UUID.fromString("")
>
> where the string is:
>
> 7dc53df5-703e-49b3-8670-b1c468f47f1f
>
> in the case of your UUID (i.e. remove the leading '{' and trailing '}' from the Guid string)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the UUID u are talking about is from java.util in J2SE. The one I am using is in J2ME.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm not entirely familiar with the j2me UUID classes - based on the source at http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/7627_UUID.java you should omit the hypens